# histogram equalization and CDF

Tags: probability, image-processing

Im having hard time understading one of the derivation steps in histogram equalization,  Wikipedia (added picture).

[derivation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vw8rw.png)

In the last sentence it seems to me like they are suggesting that the CDF of the original CDF is linear, is that true? If so, why?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your posts (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.